# Powershell, uninstalling app in remote machines, access denied

Tags: powershell

I am trying to uninstall an application from a remote computer using a powershell script. Whenever I try to access that machine's file I get access denied even though I am using the highest admin account in the system.

Here's my current code.

```
$appname1 = "app1"
$appname2 = "app2"
$comp = Read-Host -Prompt "Computer Name"
$username = Read-Host -Prompt "Username"
$password = Read-Host -AsSecureString -Prompt "password" | ConvertTo- SecureString -asPlainText -Force

$credential = New-Object 
System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)

$prod1=gwmi -computer $comp -Credential $credential win32_product  | ?{$_.name -eq "$appname1"}
$prod2=gwmi -computer $comp -Credential $credential win32_product  | ?{$_.name - Like "*$appname2*"}

if($prod1 -ne $null)
{
        $prod1.Uninstall()
}
else {
    echo ("Could not find program '" + $appname1 + "'")
}
if($prod2 -ne $null)
{
        $prod2.uninstall()
}
else {
    echo ("Could not find program '" + $appname2 + "'")
}
```

I did try different things such as Invoke-command, enable-psremoting(on both machines), set-executionpolicy bypass and remotesigned.

Comment: Why are you trying to invoke the `.Uninstall()` wmi method?  Go to the registry key and find the supported uninstall string.

Comment: Where is the code running? On your computer or another computer or server?

Comment: Are you running PowerShell as an elevated session? You know, right click and Run As Administrator?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I didn't know it required a different uninstall string.

Comment: @EBGreen on my computer, trying to connect to different computers.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician yes

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 So, I looked into Regedit, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ to look for the application that I want to uninstall. 
Both of them are not there.
Then I looked into where the application would land, 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\app1
but app1 and app2 does not have uninstalls string

Comment: Are they custom apps?  That is basically mandatory for software in Windows..

Comment: It is a Cisco application for VPN

Comment: Oh, I found it, it has one of the hex names instead of a normal name.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Now I am again in square 1.


    Invoke-Command -ComputerName  $comp -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock{
        msiexec.exe /X{467D5E81-1214-4822-9E81-C367ED8E123}
    }


Instead of getting access denied, I am now getting "unknown username/password" even though it is the same username and password that works on the machine itself(used multiple accounts too just to check).

Comment: That's because your syntax is confusing the interpreter.  Remove `{ }` from around the GUID in your call to msiexec and instead put a space between `/X GUID`

Comment: Changed to /X GUID, still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps CredSSP will help?:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.wsman.management/enable-wsmancredssp?view=powershell-6

After configuration, you would just use `Invoke-Command -Authentication CredSSP` along with the rest of your code.